# Show that $Area(\triangle BFE)=2Area(\triangle FED)$.

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

[image]

> $ABC$ and $BDE$ are two equilateral triangles such that $D$ is the midpoint of 
>   $BC$. If $AE$ intersects $BC$ at $F$, show that $Area(\triangle BFE)=2Area(\triangle FED)$

**Solution given**[image] :

[image]

I didn't understand in the solution that $FB=2FD$ .

Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\triangle ABF \sim \triangle EDF \Rightarrow \dfrac{AB}{ED} = \dfrac{BF}{DF} = \dfrac{FA}{FE}$, but $AB = 2BD=2ED \Rightarrow BF = 2FD$

Comment: $\quad$ thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, R.K.

Answer (score 1):

Let M be the midpoint of BD. Do you see EM//AD and AD = 2EM? Then it is easy to see FD = 2MF. If you come through to this point then you can deduce that BF = 2FD. Because BF = BM + MF and MD = MF + FD and BM = MD.

Comment: $\quad$ thanks!